# Using expand() in snakemake to input any file from list of directories

Tags: python, wildcard, snakemake

I have a rule that takes any and every TSV file (multiple TSVs) from a list of directories defined as `tasks`. For example:

```
tasks
    foo
        example1.tsv
        circle.tsv
    bar
        rectangle.tsv
    square
        triangle.tsv
        triangle_1.tsv
```

I then have a rule in a Snakemake workflow that runs a script on the list of files as such:

```
task_list = ["bar", "square"]

rule gather_files:
        input:
            tsv=expand("results/stats/{tasks}/*.tsv", tasks=task_list)
        output: 
            "results/plots/visualizations.pdf"
        script:
            "Rscript plot_script.R"
```

The `*.tsv` results in errors when I try to run the rule and I know it's not the correct way either. What is the best way to do this? Should I use regex to match any string in `{task}/*.tsv`? I want to limit the combinations of directories to expand on (`tasks`) but have no constraints on the filenames in them.

Answer (score 2):

This is not very elegant but should work

```
from glob import glob

task_stats = ["foo", "bar", "square"] 

rule combine_files:
        input:
            tsv=[j for i in expand("results/stats/{tasks}/*.tsv", tasks=task_stats) for j in glob(i)]
        output: 
            "results/plots/stats_visualizations.html"
        script:
            "../scripts/plot_all_stats.Rmd"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same question, and a hacky way that I used to solve this problem was by passing a directory as an input, and a matching pattern as a parameter of the rule:

```py
rule analysis:
    params:
        csvglob = "*.csv"
    input:
        folder="results/stats/{tasks}"
    output: 
        "results/plots/stats_visualizations.html"
    script:
        "../scripts/plot_all_stats.Rmd"
```

And in my script I read from that parameter as

```py
rootdir = snakemake.input["folder"]
csvglob = snakemake.params["csvglob"]
files = glob(f"{rootdir}/{csvglob}")
```

I take a similar approach would also work for R.

Downside: - feels hacky. Upside: - quite easy to change the pattern, or manipulate and filter it from within the script.